# Spring/RestTemplate - PUT entity to server

Tags: java, json, spring, put, resttemplate

Please look at this simple code:

```
final String url = String.format("%s/api/shop", Global.webserviceUrl);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("X-TP-DeviceID", Global.deviceID);
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

HttpEntity<Shop[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Shop[].class);
shops = response.getBody();
```

As you can see, above code is intended to GET list of shops from server (in json format) and map response to array of Shop objects.
Now I need to PUT new shop, for example as /api/shop/1. Request entity should have exactly the same format as returned one.

Should I add /1 to my url, create new Shop class object, with all fields filled with my values I want to put and then use exchange with HttpMethod.PUT?

Please, clarify  it for me, I'm beginner with Spring. Code example would be appreciated.

[edit]
I'm double confused, because I just noticed also method RestTemplate.put(). So, which one should I use? Exchange or put()?

Comment: You likely want to use POST to create a new object, and PUT to update an existing object.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could try something like :

```
    final String url = String.format("%s/api/shop/{id}", Global.webserviceUrl);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("X-TP-DeviceID", Global.deviceID);
    Shop shop= new Shop();
    Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
    param.put("id","10")
    HttpEntity<Shop> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Shop>(shop, headers);
    HttpEntity<Shop[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, Shop[].class, param);

    shops = response.getBody();
```

the put returns void whereas exchange would get you a response, the best place to check would be documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

Comment: I assume I should use requestEntity instead of entity as exchange parameter? Also, why id is hasmap, do you mean possible multiple url parameters?

Comment: yes, its for multiple url parameters. I think there is an overloaded version which doesn't require map, you could directly pass the url parameter as well as query parameter (if needed). updated the answer with requestEntity instead of entity.

Comment: Great answer!
I know it's a minor thingy but please correct this line: param.put(“id”,”10”)
as this is different than simple quote characters, I just copied the code into an editor and it revealed those characters are different.

Comment: Thanks bro! I dont know because having postEntity, getEntity and patchEntity in RestTemplateHelper and doesent having putEntity ‍♂️